# Angular 2 Typescript class property allows incorrect type to be assigned

Tags: angular, typescript

Why doesn't this cause an error?

```
export class Foo {
    a: any;
    b: number;
}

export class MyClass {
    public data: Array<Foo>;
}
```

I assign a string to property of MyClass and no error is caused. Shouldn't this cause an error?

```
export class MyComponent {    
    classyClass: MyClass;

    constructor() {
        this.classyClass = new MyClass();
    }

    myFunction = function() {
       this.classyClass.data = 'abc';
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
myFunction = function() {
    this.classyClass.data = 'abc';
}
```

then `this` will point to `myFunction`s instance and not to your component. You should use:

```
myFunction(){
    this.classyClass.data = 'abc';
}
```